# PC with 2 RAMs (1GB alredy running+1GB new) showing only 1GB RAM older

Tags: memory

my PC is running on 1GB ram(DDR2), 320 GB HDD and windows 8.but now i bought 1GB DDR2 extra. But my PC is not show my newest Ram memory. it does not start with new Ram. Please tell me what should i do to boot ram without reinstall windows.

Comment: What motherboard does your computer have? Have you fitted the RAM cards on the same colored channels?

Comment: See if your RAM stick is supported by your mobo

Comment: Check which slot the RAM should be fitted to, it should probably be fitted using alternate slots

Answer (score 3):

The problem is unlikely to be a Windows problem or require a Reinstall as the OS will pick it up automatically - it will either be that the RAM has not been correctly seated, or is the wrong type of RAM or the slot is not functional.  Try reseating the RAM, and checking it is showing as available in the BIOS.